# Is xid value unique in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is xid or Transaction Id value unique in redshift system tables like stl_query? process Id or PID can have duplicate entries over time, but for xid is it guaranteed to be unique. Couldn't find proper documentation on aws redshift related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's autoincremented,

`select txid_current();`

above query returns the current transaction id, on executing it multiple times the xid or Transaction Id gets incremented. But no documental mention found on AWS redshift documentation.